# .Net Core webapi expection catch middleware not catch exception throw from ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

i wrote a gloabl exception catch middleware like this:

```cs
  public GlobalExceptionCatchMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<GlobalExceptionCatchMiddleware> logger)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if(ex is CustomException)
                {
                    var result = new ResponseResult
                    {
                        message = "" + ex.Message,
                        code = 200,
                        success = false
                    };
                    AddCors(ref context);
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogError($"System Uncatched error：{ex.StackTrace}");
                    var msg=TranslateErrorMessage(ex.Message);
                    var result = new ResponseResult
                    {
                        message =   msg,
                        code = 200,
                        success = false
                    };
                    AddCors(ref context);
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
                }
                
            }
        }
```

and i use a actionfilter to check user privilage :

```cs
public class PrivilegeFilterAttribute:ActionFilterAttribute
{
  //....
 public override async void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            throw new System.Exception("test throw error");
            // do something ...
            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }

  //....
}
```

and use globalexceptioncatchmidlleware at startup.cs:

```cs
  
   app.UseMiddleware<GlobalExceptionCatchMiddleware>(); 
   app.UseRouting();
   // ...
   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

the throwed error is not catched by middleware, why? What is the order of execution of filter and middleware?

Comment: why are you writing your own middleware it is already provided and you can customize the response. chek this link for best practices https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @CodingMytra  the above code was written when I was just learning .net core. and now I know that .net core provides a built-in exception handler

Comment: then you should use now built-in exception handler and get rid of all this unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, i found the solution: just remove `async` and replace all `await` with `.Result`, then global exception handler can catch the exception thrown from action filter.

to be honest, i still didn't figure out the reason, but at least the problem is solved, isn't it?

Comment: Just be aware that using .Result will block the current thread. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async#important-info-and-advice